# What are the bonus extras in the Oglaf book?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, oglaf

The description for [the first book](https://topatoco.com/collections/oglaf/products/og-book01) collecting the [*Oglaf* webcomic](https://oglaf.com) <sup>*Warning, not always SFW*</sup>, claims that

> There's also bonus extras, never seen before and printed in internet-proof ink, (...)

**What are these extras?**

Is it just a couple of extra pictures or are there additional stories?

Are similar extras present in the second book as well?
<sub>*(Yes, technically that's a different question, but it's closely related enough to ask it in one question)*</sub>

Comment: Replace "not always" with "almost never".

Comment: @OrangeDog depends on your place of work.

Comment: Hmmm. My school's network filter blocks the site as "pornography." @OrangeDog

Comment: @Shokhet that is probably accurate.